# How Do I Find All Possible discrete Values and Occurences

Tags: r

Given: `yi <- c(1,2,4,4,7,7,7,8)`

Now sample 4 units from the 8 above with simple random sampling with out replacement.

I would like to find all the possible discrete values for all (8 choose 4 =) 70 combinations and the number each discrete value occurs.

For example:
t1 = (1,2,4,4) = 11, happens only once
t2 ...

Comment: This is a math problem, not a programming question.

Comment: @SeñorO It is best treated as a math problem... but there is no reason it can't be a programming problem.

Comment: @SeñorO -- Tell that to [Donald Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth#Works) ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `combinat::combn`:

```
library(combinat)
all.poss <- t(combn(yi, 4))

dim(all.poss)
# [1] 70 4
table(rowSums(all.poss))
# 11 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 29 
#  1  6  2  3  7  4  6 12  6  4  7  3  2  6  1
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that `combinat::combn` is different than `utils::combn`, i.e. that there is actually a need to load pkg::combinat?